MUI Paper Prop Background Color change with CSS Variable
I need to change MUI select menu background color when toggle theme to dark and light. I am using custom theme provider and its work for select {sx: } but not work for PaperProp { sx: }
<FormControl sx={{ margin: 0, minWidth: 300 }}>
          <Select
            value={selectedCategory}
            onChange={handleCategory}
            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Without label' }}
            sx={{
              color: 'var(--textColor)', 
              backgroundColor:'var(--input-bg)', // <--------- this work with according to dark and light
              boxShadow: 'none', '.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': { border: 0 },
              '&.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
                borderColor: 'var(--toggleColor)',
              },
              '&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
                borderColor: 'var(--toggleColor)',
              },
              '.MuiSvgIcon-root ': {
                fill: "var(--toggleDark) !important",
              }
            }}
            
            MenuProps={{
              style: {
                maxHeight: 500,
              },
            
              PaperProps: {
                sx: {
                  backgroundColor: 'var(--inputColor) ', // < ----------- this is not work with toggle always displaying globaal css :root --inputColor
                  color: 'var(--textColorInDark)',
                }
              }

              
            }}
          >
            <MenuItem value={'Select Category'}>Select Category</MenuItem>
              
          </Select>
          </FormControl>

below is my global.css it has css variables for dark and light themes
:root {
  --inputColor: #0a0f1b;
}

.dark {
  --inputColor: #0a0f1b;


}

.light {
  --inputColor: #e7e7e9;
}


can you create a sandbox to replicate this.
